# Pi 3 Model B+ can't boot after changing vRAM

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, memory, opengles, memory-split

I just got the device (Pi 3 Model B+) and am a total beginner.

I'm using NOOB/Raspbian. Every time I try to change the video ram (either through the GUI or the config.txt) the device is unable to boot, it just flickers between a black screen and the screen turning off. Even when I revert the changes of the config.txt via recovery mode, the problem persists.

I reinstalled Raspian about 4 times already, and am about to do so again, but being able to change the amount of vRAM would be nice.

I used the OpenGL driver, which I changed through raspi-config. I tried to change the vRAM to a reasonable amount (128). The only software I installed was xscreensaver, gwenview and redshift (a blue light filter that auto starts.). I'm using the official 2.5A power supply.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens (even after I revert the changes in the config)? Could it be connected to the software I installed, or OpenGL?

Thanks

[EDIT]: Solved. I was advised at the RasPi forums to get rid of NOOBS and just flash the SD card with Raspbian stretch. That solved all my problems and made the device boot 5x faster.

Comment: Are you using an HDMI screen and what resolution? Most likely an incompatibility between OpenGL and some other software. Personally I always flash Raspbian direct to sd card - don't use noobs.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was solved by getting rid of noobs.

Comment: Please make an answer about the solution you have found instead of appending it to your question. The answer will finish your question and show other users that it has a solution.

Comment: noobs is good - as long as you don't want to change a single thing with your pi!